# how can i make the following code work with both ascending and descending numbers

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement

I am using the code below to find a value in 8 [qty] fields which is closest in value to the value in [make quantity] field.
The code works as I want provided the value in the [qty] fields are ascending values. eg. 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80

The code fails if the values are descending, or mixed  eg. 80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10 or 10,30,50,40,70,20,80 etc

can anyone suggest how to handle this in a better way

```
If Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty1] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw1]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty2] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty1] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw1]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty3] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty2] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw2]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty4] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty3] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw3]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty5] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty4] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw4]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty6] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty5] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw5]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty7] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty6] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw6]

ElseIf Me![Make Quantity] <= Me![qty8] And Me![Make Quantity] > Me![qty7] Then
    materialprice = Me![raw7]

Else
    materialprice = Me![raw8]

End If
```

Comment: Do you have to keep the order of the elements?

Comment: what do you mean? if you mean [qty1] and [raw1] must stay together then yes but if you are asking if [qty2] must follow [qty1] and so on then no

Comment: Are you trying to find the 'best fit' from the eight quantities (i.e. find exact match, or find match with least quantity exceeding 'Make Quantity'? Also, it appears all of these fields are on a form, populated by some recordset?

Comment: yes the [raw1] is a price related to [qty1] the [raw2] is a price related to [qty2] etc. These values have been entered previously. Now on this current form, the user enters a make quantity, and I need to find the nearest applicable [qty] and [raw] price. Sorry if this is a confusing statement, I don't know how else to describe what I'm doing

Comment: Are there always only eight 'qty' fields (qty1-qy8), and are they all obtained from a some recordsource for your form? If so, and you desire to find an exact match or a qty with the least overage, then it would be simple to create a function to give you the answer. I can help you if that's the case, otherwise, I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes there are 8 qty's with 8 corresponding prices in a recordset. The user now enters a make quantity, and I need to find the closest qty to the make qty to use that price. eg, 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80 are qty's 5,6,7,8,9.10,11,12 are the related prices. if the user enters 46 as the make qty, then this value is between 40 and 50, and so I would use the 4th price 8. if the make qty was 77 then I would use the price 11 and so on. the code I posted does this fine , provided the values are ascending as I said, but if the are descending or mixed then the code fails.

Comment: Let's make sure I understand... you want to find the field on the form that contains either an exact match, or the field that is LESS than AND the CLOSEST match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED!! Changed code so that if QTY < lowest, default to lowest; if > highest, use highest.

Here's some code I threw together... since I don't have your data, i loaded test data into 8 pairs of textboxes (using your field names).  Note that I used the 'CHANGE' event for the 'Make Quantity' textbox to invoke the code. You can force execution however you like...

Once satisfied, comment out the Debug statements and the MsgBox.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim i   As Integer
Dim MakeQuantity    As Integer
Dim materialprice    As Double

Me.qty1 = 30: Me.qty2 = 20: Me.qty3 = 70: Me.qty4 = 50: Me.qty5 = 10: Me.qty6 = 60: Me.qty7 = 80: Me.qty8 = 70
Me.raw1 = 3.3: Me.raw2 = 2.2: Me.raw3 = 7.7: Me.raw4 = 5.5: Me.raw5 = 1.1: Me.raw6 = 6.6: Me.raw7 = 8.8: Me.raw8 = 7.7

End Sub


    Private Sub Make_Quantity_AfterUpdate()
Dim i       As Integer
Dim iDiff   As Integer
Dim iLow    As Integer
Dim iMatch  As Integer
Dim iHigh   As Integer
Dim dPriceL As Double
Dim dPriceH As Double
Dim dPriceM As Double
Dim iQtyL   As Integer
Dim iQtyH   As Integer

    iLow = 30000
    iHigh = 0
    iMatch = 10
    Debug.Print "Find Qty of: " & Me.[Make Quantity]
For i = 1 To 8
    If Int(Me("qty" & i)) <= iLow Then
        iLow = Int(Me("qty" & i))
        dPriceL = Me("raw" & i)
        iQtyL = Int(Me("qty" & i))
    End If
    If Int(Me("qty" & i)) >= iHigh Then
        iHigh = Int(Me("qty" & i))
        dPriceH = Me("raw" & i)
        iQtyH = Int(Me("qty" & i))
    End If

    iDiff = Abs(Me.[Make Quantity] - Me("qty" & i))
    If Int(Me("qty" & i)) <= Int(Me.[Make Quantity]) Then
        If iDiff <= iMatch Then
            iMatch = iDiff
            dPriceM = Me("raw" & i)
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print "i: " & i & vbTab & "Qty: " & Me("qty" & i) & vbTab & "Diff: " & iDiff & vbTab & "Raw: " & Me("raw" & i)
Next i

    If dPriceM <> 0 Then    ' Did we find a suitable match?
        MsgBox "Make Quantity: " & Me.[Make Quantity] & vbCrLf & "Price: " & dPriceM
    Else        ' Didn't find a good match; must be < lowest or > highest
        If iQtyL > Int(Me.[Make Quantity]) Then     ' Greater than lowest QTY, use Lowest QTY price...
            MsgBox "Make Quantity: " & Me.[Make Quantity] & vbCrLf & "Price: " & dPriceL
        ElseIf iQtyH < Int(Me.[Make Quantity]) Then     ' Greater than highest QTY, use highest QTY price...
            MsgBox "Make Quantity: " & Me.[Make Quantity] & vbCrLf & "Price: " & dPriceH
        Else
            MsgBox "Impossible? Asked for Qty of: " & Me.[Make Quantity] & vbCrLf & _
                "Lowest Qty: " & iQtyL & vbTab & _
                "Highest Qty: " & iQtyH

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hi wayne - thanks for this - i'll need to try it out tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: Ive modified the above code slightly and it works fine, however I need a small tweak if you can advise.  If I have quantities of 20 and 30, and the user enters a make qty of 27, I need the raw qty to be that associated with 20 not 30. The above code will pick 20 for values from 20 to 25, and then will pick 30 for values between 26 and 30. can you suggest how to achieve this. - thanks

Comment: Well, now I need more info. Will the QTY values always be MOD 10, or can they be any value? If MOD 10, then easy, if not MOD 10, then define when you take a '20' instead of a '21'.

Comment: the qty's can be any value. - think of them as break qty and prices from a supplier. eg. 10 off £2.50 20 off £2.20 30 off £2.10 - the supplier gives a better price for greater qty's, and so if the user then needs a 15 off, then the 10off price is valid aka £2.50  equally if the user enters 19 off, then the price will still be £2.50 as the second break qty hasn't been reached. Though the qty's are usually in 10's, this isn't always true, as you could have break qty's of 1,3,5,10,25 or whatever, so there is need to handle all these variations. - I hope this helps to explain what i'm trying to do

Comment: OK, what value is supposed to be returned if 'Make Quantity' is less than ALL 'qty' fields? Or will there always be a qty of 1?

Comment: if the make qty is less than all the qty's then default to smallest [qty]

Comment: I modified the code so that if you look for a QTY that is less than the lowest qty listed on the form, it will use the price associated with the lowest QTY; and if looking for a QTY greater than highest QTY on form, use the price for that one. Let me know if you have questions...

Comment: just finished testing and its great - works like a charm - thanks for your support